# margin inside/outside for CSS Paged Media rendering in AntennaHouse

Tags: css, xsl-fo, css-paged-media, print-css, antenna-house

I'm doing print layouts with HTML and CSS with AntennaHouse renderer.

A box in my content should have a left margin of 20pt on left pages and 10pt on right pages.

```
/* on left hand pages */
margin-left: 20pt;
margin-right: 10pt;

/* on right hand pages */
margin-left: 10pt;
margin-right: 20pt;
```

So the outside margin of the box should be 20pt and the inside margin 10pt.
Basically I'm looking for a syntax like this (which doesn't exist):

```
/* pseudo code */
margin-outside: 20pt;
margin-inside: 10pt;
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?
And if yes, is there an equivalent for padding inside/outside?

*XSL-FO solutions are welcome as well, as AntennaHouse has equivalent functions for FO and CSS rendering...*

Comment: in XSL-FO, the only method I'm aware of is to do this on the page level instead of individual boxes.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking  question too deep by thinking of the solution ... what is it visually you are trying to achieve? Inside/outside are usually supported on page margins and as directives for floats,

Comment: @KevinBrown: indeed I also tried solving this by using "float:outside" but this didn't worked very well... still need different paddings for left/right pages in this box then...

Comment: Sorry I cannot visualize what you want without a picture.

Answer (score 2):

If you use PrinceXML, it definitely supports margin-inside and margin-outside. I used it for laying out a novel:

```
@page {
  size: 6in 9in;
  margin-inside: 0.75in;
  margin-outside: 0.625in;
  margin-top: 1in;
  margin-bottom: 1in
}
```